# Siddhi CQEngine used within filter section

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, siddhi

My incoming event contains userId property. I'd like to be able to read the parameter value according to userId from the CQEngine. Should I implement this as extension of FunctionExecutor and use it like:

```
define stream cseEventStream (userId string, symbol string, price long, volume long);
@info(name = 'query1')
from cseEventStream [price < custom:cache(userId)]
select *
insert into Output
```

or is there some better way how to do it. The problem is that before first use of CQEngine I need to initialize it with data. Probably "start" method of the FunctionExecutor could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead with a `FunctionExecutor` and implement initialization logic within either `init()` or `start()`. Both will be called once per function usage. Calling order is `init()` followed by `start()`. However, as per API doc, it's advised to use `start()` to acquire required resources for the processing element. and `stop()` to release acquired resources.

Comment: Hi Grainier. Thank you for your response. In the meantime I've managed to implement it and it works. However do you have any idea how to inject some spring framework bean into the FunctionExecutor extension? The only way coming to my mind is some service locator. Do you have any other idea how to do it? Thank you.